# Data of GDP values of cities in the world

Tags: data-request, city, gdp

I am looking for a data which lists GDP (gross domestic product) values of all the cities in the world. I already looked at the Wikipedia page [List of cities by GDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_GDP) but the list is too limited for me. Specifically, I would like to have the data for each city which has airport in it.

Does anybody know of such an exhaustive list of cities for GDP?

Comment: I think the question is a little ambiguous because (1) cities don't have clearly defined GDP because they often include neighboring suburbs or regions, (2) airports most definitely service regions and not cities, and (3) GDP is defined for nations and often large regions, but not cities. If anything, you want Gross Metropolitan Product ([GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_metropolitan_product))

Comment: @philshem: I also think the same to some extent. But then I found a wikipedia article for list of cities according to GDP.

Comment: FWIW, the PwC study from 2008 is here, with 151 cities and some more data than the wiki page. http://pwc.blogs.com/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/progress?id=M2MGbrRqFKmSwAfvR1mwBMvetMCRHedZPBeqE-x1Upk,&dl

Answer (score 1):

It's only the US, but as a start, the Bureau of Economic Analysis (BEA).

[**Gross Domestic Product by Metropolitan Area**](https://www.bea.gov/newsreleases/regional/gdp_metro/gdp_metro_newsrelease.htm)

> Real gross domestic product (GDP) increased in 292 metropolitan areas in 2015, led by growth in professional and business services; wholesale and retail trade; and finance, insurance, real estate, rental and leasing, according to statistics on the geographic breakout of GDP released today by the Bureau of Economic Analysis. Collectively, real GDP for U. S. metropolitan areas increased 2.5 percent in 2015 after increasing 2.3 percent in 2014.

There is historical data, until 2015 at the time of writing, which can be corrected for inflation.

Each region can be divided into industrial sectors.

There is a [data explorer tool](https://www.bea.gov/iTable/index_regional.cfm) and a programming [API](https://www.bea.gov/API/signup/)

[image]